# Différences de la prononciation de : e, é, è, ê et ai

Tags: prononciation, phonétique, diacritiques

Y a-t-il toujours des différences de prononciation entre les formes accentuées de *e*:

> e, é, è, ê, ai ?

Plus spécifiquement, sont-elles perceptibles et doit-on toujours les prononcer différemment ?
Pour clarifier:

- J’ajoute *ai* du point de vue phonétique, même s'il a une graphie différente.
- Je ne parle pas des cas évidents, comme parle/parlé ou fait/faille, mais plutôt des variations en qualité de la voyelle entre [e], [ɛ], [ə]. Par exemple, les qualités des *é* et *e* dans les mots *différence*, *différemment*.

*Question supplémentaire:*
Y a-t-il des règles fixes de prononciation? Il me semble que :

- *è* est toujours prononcé comme *ai*, ouvert [ɛ]. Egalement *e* a cette valeur au début d'un mot
- *é* est toujours [e]
- *e* est [ə] (s'il n'est pas muet)

Pour le contexte: ma langue maternelle est le russe qui ne distingue que 5(6) voyelles de base : /i/, /e/, /a/, /o/, /u/ (même s'il y a des variations dans leur prononciation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il faut distinguer l'orthographe de la prononciation. Quand un E est accentué, on sait toujours quand il se prononce. Par contre le E non accentué a plusieurs prononciations.

- **`é`** est prononcé **/[e](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_mi-ferm%C3%A9e_ant%C3%A9rieure_non_arrondie)/**.
- **`è`**, **`ê`** et (plus rare) **`ë`** sont prononcés **/[ɛ](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_mi-ouverte_ant%C3%A9rieure_non_arrondie)/**, une voyelle plus ouverte.
- Le digraphe **`ai`** est en général prononcé /ɛ/, mais il y a des exceptions où il est prononcé /e/ et des mots où la prononciation de beaucoup de locuteurs natifs fluctue, soit en fonction du contexte, soit librement.
- La lettre **E sans accent**, quand c'est une voyelle isolée, est plus compliquée. Voici quelques règles courantes, mais attention, je ne mentionne pas tous les cas.

  - Si E est suivie de **deux consonnes**, on prononce /ɛ/. Exemples : *couvert* /ku.vɛʁ/, *cette* /sɛt/, *belle* /bɛl/, *perte* /pɛʁt/, *sieste* /sjɛst/, …
  - Quand E est suivie d'**une seule consonne**, c'est un son plus fermé /[ə](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_moyenne_centrale)/. En français courant, le son /ə/ est très souvent omis. Exemples : *devoir* /də.vwaʁ/, *revers* /ʁə.vɛʁ/, …
  - En **fin de mot**, E est muet. Exemples : *une* /yn/, *madame* /ma.dam/, …
  - Dans **`en`** + autre consonne et quelquefois **`em`** + consonne : le N ou le M transforme la voyelle en une voyelle nasale. Pour E, la voyelle nasale est /ɑ̃/ (comme `an`). Exemples : *en* /ɑ̃/, *dent* /dɑ̃/, *sens* /sɑ̃s/, *enfant* /ɑ̃.fɑ̃/, ** … Cas particulier : dans la finale `-ien(s)` et quelques autres cas de finale `-en`, le `en` se prononce /ɛ̃/ (comme `in`). Exemples : *bien* /bjɛ̃/, *moyen* /mwa.jɛ̃/, …

    - En général, la règle de nasalisation est plus forte que la règle des deux voyelles, sauf pour `enn` et `emm`. Exemples : *vent* /vɑ̃/, *vente* /vɑ̃t/, *embauche* /ɑ̃.boʃ/, *benne* /bɛn/, *lemme* /lɛm/… Attention, il y a beaucoup d'exceptions.
  - Les mots d'une seule syllabe ont souvent une prononciation différente en français. Dans les mots où la seule voyelle est un E :

    - Mots de la forme consonne(s) + `e` : /ə/. Exemples : *ce* /sə/, *le* /lə/, *que* /kə/, …
    - Mots de la forme consonne(s) + `es` : /e/ ou /ɛ/. *tu es* /ty.ɛ/ ou /ty.e/, *les* /le/ ou /lɛ/, …
    - Mots de la forme consonne(s) + `en` : voyelle nasale /ɑ̃/ (voir plus haut).
    - Mots de la forme consonne(s) + `E` + autre consonne : /ɛ/ et la consonne n'est pas muette. Exemples : *mer* /mɛʁ/, *sel* /sɛl/, *net* /nɛt/, …
  - Des exception importante :

    - La finale `-er` se prononce toujours /e/ dans les infinitifs, et dans la plupart des mots qui ne sont pas des infinitifs. Exemples : *aller* /a.le/, *aimer* /ɛ.me/, *courrier* /kuʁje/, …
    - La finale `-ent` dans les conjugaisons (et seulement dans les conjugaisons) est muette. Exemple : *ils aiment* /il.z‿ɛm/ rime avec *il aime* /il.ɛm/. *Ils rhésident* (du verbe *résider) /il.ʁe.zid/, chacun est donc *un rhésident* /œ̃.ʁe.zi.dɑ̃/.

Encore une fois, les règles sont compliquées, je n'ai pas tout expliqué, il y a beaucoup de sous-règles et d'exceptions.

Ces sons peuvent être groupés en trois catégories : les voyelles ouvertes /ɛ/ et /e/, la voyelle moyenne /ə/, et les voyelles nasales. Il n'y a jamais de variation possible entre ces trois groupes.

**Entre /ɛ/ et /e/**, il y a des variations possibles suivant l'accent. Certains accents (surtout dans le sud de la France) ne prononcent le son [ɛ] que dans certaines syllabes accentuées, et prononcent [e] ailleurs. La majorité des accents distinguent les deux sons, mais ont des variations possibles dans certains mot. Par exemple *des*, *les*, *ces*, *mes*, *tes*, … sont plus souvent [e] mais peuvent devenir [ɛ] en fonction du contexte, de l'emphase et en variation libre.

**Le son /ə/** est très souvent omis quand on arrive à prononcer les consonnes qui sont autour sans une voyelle au milieu. Dans les mots d'une syllabe qui sont suivis d'un mot qui commence par un son voyelle, l'omission est obligatoire et on écrit le mot avec une apostrophe : *je* + *aime* → *j'aime* /ʒɛm/ … On considère souvent ce son comme un [schwa](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa). Une minorité, surtout dans le sud de la France, prononce le /ə/ systématiquement et même les E muets en fin de mot, et la réalisation est beaucoup plus fermée : [[ø](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_mi-ferm%C3%A9e_ant%C3%A9rieure_arrondie)].

Le français a 16 voyelles dans les dictionnaires de France, au moins 12 ou 13 dans les accents qui ont le moins de voyelles distinctes, et quelques voyelles supplémentaires qui n'existent que dans une minorité d'accents. Bon courage !

Comment: *Certains accents (surtout dans le sud de la France) n'ont pas de son [ɛ], seulement [e].* Tu penses à quel accents ? À ma connaissance, aucun accent « du midi » ne connais pas le [ɛ], présent par exemple dans *chef, fête ou Marseille*. Tu inclus peut-être l'accent corse ?

Comment: Merci beaucoup. J'ai été conscient des règles principales, mais ça me prendrait beaucoup de la recherche à les mettre ensemble.

Comment: C'est effectivement très compliqué y compris pour les locuteurs natifs. En classe de CE2, la justification pour noter l'accent ou non est basée sur les syllabes, c'est à dire que l'on n'accentue que les *e* de fin de syllabe. Mais du coup la difficulté est le découpage en syllabes... et c'est à mes yeux incompréhensible.

Comment: @jlliagre Je pensais plutôt au sud-ouest dans la région de [tɔlɔzø], mais effectivement je crois qu'il y a quand même quelques réalisations ouvertes dans les syllabes accentuées. C'est un peu vague pour moi avec mon accent du nord de la Loire dans lequel il n'y a pas d'accentuation.

Comment: @jlliagre Je viens de Provence (et même si je n'ai pas l'accent le plus prononcé), on a fortement tendance à prononcer les 'ai' comme des 'é'. Typiquement, toutes mes terminaisons à l'imparfait sont prononcées comme des /e/. On sait prononcer les 'è' et les 'ê' par contre.

Comment: @JeremyGrand Oui, bien sûr, j'ai le m**ê**me ! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Les différences sont perceptibles pour les oreilles françaises mais prononcer [e] alors que [ɛ] est le phonème attendu n'entraîne pas vraiment de problème de compréhension.

Certains accents régionaux le font d'ailleurs systématiquement suivant la position de la voyelle. Par exemple « du lait » peut être prononcé [dyle] et pas [dylɛ].

Dans certains cas, les deux prononciations se rencontrent même en français « standard » (c'est à dire parisien) : *essai* peut être prononcé [ɛsɛ] ou [esɛ] ou [ese].

Comment: Y-a-t-il des regles de prononciation? Par exemple, *e* est prononcé comme *ai/è* au debut d'un mot, etc. Une question plus pratique : peut-on apprendre à mettre les accentes dans l'ecriture sans le memoriser, à la base de valeur phonétique ?

Comment: Difficile de parler de règles alors que la prononciation peut varier suivant les individus. S'il fallait en définir une, le son [ɛ] est assez systématique pour les voyelles *è*, *ê*, *ë* et pour un *e* devant une consonne double ou une consonne finale prononcée (com**è**te, no**ë**l, **e**lle, char**e**tte, am**e**r).

Comment: Ce qui me perturbe le plus à l'ecriture, c'est la distinction entre *é* et *e* au milieu d'un mot.

Comment: Si on prend *différemment* - la dernière *e* n'est pas accentuée, car il s-agit du suffixe *-ment*, la deuxième est peut-être parce qu'elle a la prononciation nasale dans *différence* ou on ne peut pas avoir une accente, Par contre, je ne vois pas raison pour accentuer la première... sauf si on veut souligner que ce n'est pas un schwa, qu'elle doit être prononcée.

Comment: Les noms des lettres sont masculins en français (Le E, pas la E). *ENT* est en effet une nasale donc ni [e], ni [ɛ], le deuxième *E* du mot est atypique puisqu'on le prononce comme un *A* (dénasalisation du -ent de différ**ent**), le premier *E* doit être accentué car on prononce [dif**e**ʁamɑ̃]. Sans cet accent, ç'aurait été un schwa qui aurait pu être muet, ce qui n'est jamais le cas (pas de [difʁamɑ̃]).

Comment: Merci pour ce remarque - J'ai eu des doute à propos du genre des lettres.

Answer (score 0):

I have found very helpful tables from the [*Manuel de français* by Popova and Kazakova](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/5903262481), a textbook for Russian speakers that have seen more than 20 editions. As far as non-nasalized vowels are concerned, this book distinguishes open and closed 'e' ([ɛ] and [e]) and its rounded versions ([œ] and [ø]), shwa ([ə]) being considered as a reduced [œ]. I provide below their tables in my translation.

It is necessary to point out that we are talking about a soviet-era textbook that has seen many editions - it is based on an old version of pronunciation, which might significantly predate even the first publication of the book, as during the Soviet era not many Russians had a chance to practice their language skills abroad. The authors claim to base their rules on Parisian pronunciation, but it was probably even more standartized for pedagogical purposes. On the other hand, I heard on more than one occasion native French positively commenting on the linguistic abilities of Russians with background in diplomatic corps or professional translation: *La dame parle français très bien!* is a rare compliment in France, where people are usually very short of patience for bad pronunciation and grammatical errors.

**Remarks:**

- Since the textbook is written for Russians, it assumes that every word or word group has a stress, which in French always falls on the last syllable (In my experience French tend to deny that in their langauge stress exists at all).
- *Closed syllable* is the one ending with a pronounced consonant, *open syllable* end with a pronounced vowel

**Remark for Russian speakers:**
[ɛ] and [e] roughly correspond to Russian "э" in words "это" and "пень". For [œ] the mouth takes a shape, as if one is washing it after having brushed your teeth, whereas [ø] tends toward Russian "ы".

**[ɛ]**
Sound | Spelling | Position | Examples
---|---|---|---
[ɛ] | **è** || crème

- | **ê** || tête
- | **e** | in a closed syllable | traverse
- | **e** | before two identical consonants | adresse
- | **et** | in the end of a word | cabaret, elle met
- | **ai** | | paire
- | **ei** || beige
- | **est** | (3rd place singular of être) |

**[e]**
Sound | Spelling | Position | Examples
---|---|---|---
[e] | **é** | | armée

- | **er** | in the end of a word, when "r" is not pronounced | marcher
- | **ez** | in the end of a word | répétez
- | monosyllabic auxiliary words **les, des, mes, tes, ses, ces, et** ||

**[œ]** and **[ə]**
Sound | Spelling | Position | Examples
---|---|---|---
[œ] | **eu** | before a pronounced consonant, except [z] | déjeuner, fleur

- | **oeu** | before a pronounced consonant | soeur
  [ə] | **e** | in monosyllabic words | je, me, ce, le, que, se, ...
- | **e** | in open unstressed syllable | regarder

**[ø]**
Sound | Spelling | Position | Examples
---|---|---|---
[ø] | **eu** | in the end of a word or before a mute consonant | adieu, il veut, sérieux

- | **eu** | before sound [z] | sérieuse
- | **oeu** | in the end of a word or before a mute consonant | voeu, noeud