# Les règles pour "é/è/e" ?

Tags: orthographe

Y a-t-il des règles (ou des moyens mnémoniques) pour se souvenir quand il faut écrire « é » (*e accent aigu*) ou « è » (*e accent grave*) ?

Plus précisément :

- Puisque ["è" correspond à un son plus ouvert que celui de "é/e"](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/45396/9870), on peut apprendre à le distinguer en perfectionnant la prononciation. (En mon expérience, les locuteurs de certaines langues apparemment n'ont aucune difficulté avec celle-ci, comme, par exemple, des hongrois, car les deux sons sont différents dans leur langue maternelle.)
- L'accent circonflexe, "ê" pose moins de problèmes, car il est présent dans relativement peu de mots.
- On utilise toujours "e" sans accent où il s'agit de sons nasals (typiquement devant "n/m + consonne"
- On écrit "e" sans accent également* dans les graphèmes à plusieurs voyelles, comme *eu*, *eau*.
- Le participe passé finit avec "é" et parfois en "ée" (dans les cas bien connus.)
- Les formes féminines sont marquées par *e* sans accent.
- Il y a certains verbes (à mémoriser) ou l'accent paraît lors de leur conjugaison, comme *acheter -> j'achète*

Les cas où j'ai des difficultés sont:

- L'utilisation de "é/e" au début de mot. Par exemple, on écrit *échantillon*, *étoile*, mais *escargot*, *employé*, *espèce* - s'agit-il ici simplement d'un cas rare où le mot commençant avec *e* n'a pas d'accent sur la première lettre ?
- Les situations ou *é/e* se trouve au milieu du mot, particulièrement ou le mot contient plusieurs *e*: *être présent*, *télévision*, *révélation*, *pentecôte* - la raison de l'orthographe donnée est-elle à rechercher dans de l'origine du mot ? (Maintenant, alors que je cherche des exemples, je ne trouve rien sans accent, sauf *pentecôte* qui est assez à part. Mais, comme l'accentuation me pose souvent des difficultés, je vais essayer de compléter cette liste dans le futur. Doit-on simplement utiliser *"é"* dans tous les cas, qui ne sont pas couverts par les règles mentionnées ci-dessus?)

**Mots ajoutés:**

- (*e* au milieu sans accent) : *lettre*, *identité*, *relation*, *profession*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. On ne met jamais d'accent à un *E* placé devant un *S* ou une consonne double (ex: prof**ess**ion, l**ett**re), et ce *E* est prononcé comme s'il avait un accent grave (è)¹. ***Em**ployé* et *id**en**tité* sont des cas différents, déjà décrits, de consonne nasale (\ɑ̃).
2. Le deuxième *E* de pent**e**côte ne prend pas d'accent car, quand il est prononcé, ce qui n'est le cas que dans une prononciation soignée ou dans le sud de la France, il prend le son \ə\.

¹ La distinction entre les phonèmes \e\ et \ɛ\ n'est pas ce qu'il y a de plus important lors de l'apprentissage du français car il n'y a que très peu de paires minimales et elles ne sont effectives que dans certaines régions. Il est plus important de prononcer *E* différemment (\ə\). Les hispanophones, qui ne connaissent dans leur langue que cinq voyelles phonologiques (contre 14 à 16 en français), n'utilisent souvent lors de leur phase d'apprentissage que le son \e\ pour rendre tout ou partie des six voyelles françaises suivantes : \e\, \ɛ\, \ə\, \œ\, \ø\ et \ɛ̃\, et ça ne nous empêche en général pas de comprendre ce qu'ils disent.

Answer (score 3):

Concernant les mots commençant par un *e* non accentué, ça peu paraître surprenant mais l'immense majorité se prononcent théoriquement "*è*" (/ɛ/), sauf bien sûr les digrammes *en*, *em*, *eu*, etc. qui sont prononcés selon leurs propres règles. Les mots commençant par un *è* sont d'ailleurs extrêmement rares.

Tous les mots commençant par un *e* non accentué "devraient" se prononcer /ɛ/, et c'est ce que tu trouveras dans la plupart des [dictionnaires](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/escargot) incluant la phonétique. En pratique, ça varie selon les accents, les régions, les gens (et parfois même l'intonation et le contexte), au même titre que les mots "*lait*" et "*projet*" sont prononcés tantôt [/lɛ/](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/lait) et [/pʁɔ.ʒɛ/](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/projet) et tantôt /le/ et /pʁo.ʒe/. En pratique, ce qu'on entend est souvent un son entre les deux, moins marqué que dans d'autres mots comme "*peine*" ou "*élève*".

Donc la question c'est pas tant "*Pourquoi on met pas d'accent aigu alors qu'on dit éscargot* ?" mais plutôt : "*Pourquoi on dit éscargot alors qu'on devrait dire èscargot ?*"

---

Voici la liste complète des mots commençant par un *è* :

> ès, Ève, ère, èbe, èche.

Étant donné qu'on a que des mots très courts, je penche pour une raison purement esthétique.

Comment: d'ailleurs est-ce qu'on prononce *éscargot* ou bien *èscargot*. Sans doute un peu entre les deux.

Answer (score 2):

Les références utilisées pour cette réponse : « [Français Facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-110491.php) », une liste orthographique du français et des références variées de prononciation (orales et écrites).

L'exposé qui suit n'est probablement  pas complet ;  il doit rester  d'autres particularités  à collecter, mais pour l'instant je dois m'en tenir à la présente ébauche ; elle doit d'ailleurs déjà donner des points de départ à une plus ample recherche. Les listes fournies ne sont pas complètes, sauf une.

**A**

Si e est la **première lettre** du mot et s'il est  **suivi d'une** ou **deux consonnes**, e est toujours écrit **é**, prononcé **\e\**, sauf exception.

Cela est aussi vrai lorsque e est suivi de o, seule voyelle après e qui ne forme pas un digramme (peu de mots).

> étonner, étirer, état, épice, élément, étudiant, étui, érable, …
>
> écluse, éplucher, écrire, église, …
>
> éthanol, éther, éthiopienne, éthique, éthos, éthylomètre, éthylotest, éthylène, éthérique, éthérisation, éthériser, éthérisme, éthérisée, éthéromane, éthéromanie, éthérée, …
>
> évhémérisme,
>
> Éole, Éos, éocène, éolienne, éolipyle, éon, éosine, éosinophile, éosinophilie

**EXCEPTIONS**

**e est écrit sans accent, prononcé é, parfois è si**

- **suivi de x**

> exact, exercice, extrême, exempt, excellent, excès, exhaler, exiler, …

- **suivi d'une consonne double sauf « mm » et « nn »**

> ebbe (Dernière transcr. ds Littré : è-b')
> ecce, ecchymose, ecclésiale, ecclésiaste, ecclésiastique, ecclésiastique, ecclésiastiquement, ecclésiologie, ecclésiologique, eccéité,
>
> effacement, effacer, effarante, effarement, effectif, effectuer, effeuiller, efficace, effort, effroi
>
> elle, ellipse,
> errance, errante, errata, erratique, erratiquement, erratum, errements, errer, erreur, erronée, erronément,
> essai, essaim, essaimage, essaimer, essaimée,

- **suivi de deux consonnes dont la première est r**

> erbine, erbium, erg, erg, ergastoplasme, ergastule, ergatif, ergative, ergativité, ergodicité, ergodique, ergographe, ergol, ergologie, ergométrie, ergométrique, ergonome, ergonomie, ergonomique, ergonomiste, ergostérol, ergot,
> ergotage, ergoter, ergoterie, ergoteuse, ergothérapeute, ergothérapie, ergotine, ergotisme, ergotée, erlenmeyer, ermitage, ermite, erpétologie, erpétologique, erpétologiste, ers, ersatz, erse, erse, erseau,

- **suivi de deux consonnes dont la première est s**

> Escaut, Esch-sur-Alzette, Eschyle, Esculape, Esdras, Esméralda, Esneux, Espagne, Espelette,[…] escale, escalier, escaliéteuse, escalope, escaloper, escamotable, escamotage, escamoter, escamoteuse, […]  esthéticienne, esthétique, esthétique, esthétiquement, esthétisante, esthétisation, esthétiser, esthétisme, esthétisée,[…] estérification, estérifier, estérifiée, eszett

[liste entière](https://textup.fr/675603Ug) (qui devrait être assez complète)

- **suivi de « ct » (prefixe « ecto » )**

> ecthyma, ectoblaste, ectoderme, ectodermique, ectogenèse, ectoparasite, ectopie, ectopique
> ectoplasme, ectotherme, ectropion

**e est écrit sans accent, prononcé /ɑ̃/ avec la lettre qui suit si**

- **suivi de deux consonnes dont la première est m ou n**

> emporter, emprise, emmener, embellir, …
>
> entonnoir, enliser, enfouir, entrainer, ennoblir, enneiger  …
>
> EXCEPTION : ennemi  **\ɛn.mi\**

**AUTRES EXCEPTIONS**

> eh
> Eva, Evan, Eve, Evere, Everest, Evergem, Evrard
> Ève, ès, ère, èbe (variante orth. de « ebbe »), èche
> êta
> être
> ecdysone, ecstasy, ectasie

**B**

1.

En milieu de mots e n'est pas accentué avant les consonnes doubles ou avant x et sa prononciation n'est \ɛ\  que dans les cas suivants : «  annexe, vexe, sexe, apex » (limité aux exemples donnés ci-dessous, pas une liste complète) ; pour les autres mots, en particulier ceux à consonnes doubles, elle est \e\ ou \ɛ\ ou indéfinie, entre les deux.

> impeccable, meccano, peccadille, Armageddon, Eddie, reddition, Jefferson,
> beffroi, greffe, Alex, Alexandre, Mexique, Texas, annexe, vexe, sexe, apex, …

2. 

Dans le milieu des mots la prononciation de e non accentué est à rechercher souvent dans la morphologie  ;

a) Le e peut être dans la racine, et il peut avoir un accent aigu ou non ; il faut apprendre cela mot par mot.

> \ə\ chenille, chenet, penaud, tenace, menace, bretelle, déceler,  etc.
> \e\ métal, métier, mérite, pétale, ténèbres, fébrile, fétide, etc.

b) Le e peut faire partie d'une racine sur laquelle on greffe un suffixe ou un élément formant ; pas d'accent n'est utilisé mais la prononciation varie selon la prononciation de cette terminaison que l'on ajoute et selon que le e est un e euphonique ou non ; il peut être  prononcé \ə\ ou non prononcé selon l'accent et selon le choix du locuteur.

*Quelques exemples*

**dent**eler, dentelé,  -eler : généralement \ə.lɛ\ ou \ə.le\, BEAUCOUP DE NOMS EN « EAU » : **cis**eler (ciseau), **mart**eler (marteau), **monc**eler (monceau),
D'AUTRES : **écart**eler (écarter), **boss**eler (bosse)

**gant***e*let, **pot***e*let, -let (e ajouté pour l'euphonie  (\pɔ.tə.lɛ))

**armure**rie, -rie

**tabl**ette, **maison***n*ette, **minet**te (prononciation du suffixe diminutif « ette » : \ɛt\, selon le principe des consonnes doubles)

**bret**elle (\ɛl, selon la règle des consonnes doubles en milieu de mot)

3.

Dans le milieu des mots, lorsqu'on est sûr qu'il s'agit de é ou de è mais que l'on ne sait pas lequel convient, on écrit é chaque fois que la syllabe suivante a un e muet et è si ce n'est pas le cas.

> é \e\ régler, célébrer, mystérieux, aggloméré, tempéré, ébriété, pétition, métier,
> è \ɛ\ règle,  célèbre,  mystère, agglomère, tempère,

> \e\ sorcier,  panier, discret, secret,
> è \ɛ\ sorcière, discrètement, secrétaire, panière,

*Nouvelle orthographe*

> e \ə\ amonceler, déceler,
> è \ɛ\  amoncèle (ancienne orthographe : « amoncelle »), décèle,

Comment: Magnifique ! Merci beaucoup !